# Mixed Drink Calculator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is a simple mixed drink calculator written in Haskell.

There are two input files. The `drinks` file contains a list of simply formatted recipes for mixed drinks:

```
screwdriver:vodka,orange juice
white russian:vodka,coffee liqueur,cream
greyhound:gin,grapefruit juice
...
```

The `ingredients` file contains a line-separated list of presently available ingredients:

```
vodka
gin
rum
orange juice
cranberry juice
grapefruit juice
...
```

The calculator parses the drinks file and the ingredients file, determines which mixed drinks can be created with the available ingredients, and pretty-prints the results to screen:

```
Screwdriver: Vodka, Orange juice
Greyhound: Gin, Grapefruit juice
...
```

It's a simple program, but I want to improve my code style and make my Haskell more idiomatic.

```hs
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Data.Char
import Data.List

type Drink = (DrinkName, [Ingredient])
type DrinkName = String
type Ingredient = String

-- parsing the file of drink recipes                                                                                                                                                                        
drinksFile ∷ GenParser Char st [Drink]
drinksFile = endBy drink (char '\n')

-- parsing each drink recipe                                                                                                                                                                                
drink ∷ GenParser Char st Drink
drink = do first ← drinkName
           next ← recipe
           return (first, next)

-- parsing the drink name                                                                                                                                                                                   
drinkName ∷ GenParser Char st DrinkName
drinkName = do name ← many (noneOf ":")
               sep ← many (char ':')
               return name

-- parsing the recipe into a list of ingredients                                                                                                                                                            
recipe ∷ GenParser Char st [Ingredient]
recipe = sepBy (many (noneOf ",\n")) (char ',')

-- returns true iff the drink can be made with the given ingredients                                                                                                                                        
canMake ∷ [Ingredient] → Drink → Bool
canMake ingredients drink = all (flip elem ingredients) recipe
                            where recipe = snd drink

-- returns the drinks that can be made with the given ingredients                                                                                                                                           
filterByIngredients ∷ [Drink] → [Ingredient] → [Drink]
filterByIngredients drinks ingredients = filter (canMake ingredients) drinks

-- pretty prints a drink with its recipe                                                                                                                                                                    
printDrink ∷ Drink → String
printDrink (drinkName, recipe) = intercalate " " (map capitalize (words drinkName)) ++
                                ": " ++
                                intercalate ", " (map capitalize recipe)
                                where capitalize (x : xs) = toUpper x : xs

main = do drinks ← readFile "drinks"
          ingredients ← readFile "ingredients"
          case parse drinksFile "drinksFile" drinks of
               Left error → do putStrLn "Error parsing drinks file."
               Right parsedDrinks → mapM_ (putStrLn ∘ printDrink) 
                                          (filterByIngredients parsedDrinks 
                                                               (lines ingredients))
```

Comment: Can you either remove unicode syntax or upload the file to hpaste or other place where I can easily get bit-exact downloads from? Somehow I get parse errors.

Comment: +1 Yes, making ***many*** mixed drinks is very idiomatic for Haskell. Now we just need a comprehensive `drinks.txt` file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Good News:

Architecturally, your code looks very well designed. I can't think of any language features that would significantly improve your code's architecture. That leaves only function semantics and readability.

### Advise:

This advise isn't specific to idiomatic Haskell but rather general code readability.

Your current main method does a little too much. the contents of main should have a high level of abstraction. Consider abstracting the work done at the end of your main function:

```
main = do drinks      <- readFile "drinks"
          ingredients <- readFile "ingredients"
          putStrLn $ 
              case parse drinksFile "drinksFile" drinks of
              Left error         -> "Error parsing drinks file."
              Right parsedDrinks -> showPossibleDrinks parsedDrinks (lines ingredients)

showPossibleDrinks :: [Drink] -> [Ingredient] -> String
showPossibleDrinks drinks ingredients = showDrinks $ filterByIngredients drinks ingredients

showDrinks :: [Drink] -> String
showDrinks =  unlines . map printDrink
```

Here we have abstracted the process of printing the possible drinks into two sub methods. This provides greater readability and also allows us to change the return type of `case` from `IO` to `String`. Hence the `putStrLn` outside the `case` statement.

---

By changing the argument order of a few functions, we can  move the functions towards [*pointfree*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) form:

```
canMake :: [Ingredient] -> Drink -> Bool
canMake ingredients = all (flip elem ingredients) . snd

filterByIngredients :: [Ingredient] -> [Drink] -> [Drink]
filterByIngredients ingredients = filter (canMake ingredients)

main = do drinks      <- readFile "drinks"
          ingredients <- readFile "ingredients"
          putStrLn $
              case parse drinksFile "drinksFile" drinks of
              Left error         -> "Error parsing drinks file."
              Right parsedDrinks -> showPossibleDrinks (lines ingredients) parsedDrinks

showPossibleDrinks :: [Ingredient] -> [Drink] -> String
showPossibleDrinks = showDrinks . (filterByIngredients ingredients)
```

Given the succinctness of your methods, moving towards [*pointfree*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) form is quite readable and more idiomatic.

---

If we import the [**`<$>`**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--36--62-) operator from [**`Control.Applicative`**](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html) after transposing the function's arguments we can make `filterByIngredients` completely [*pointfree*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree):

```
filterByIngredients :: [Ingredient] -> [Drink] -> [Drink]
filterByIngredients =  filter <$> canMake
```

---

You can make the following equivalence substitutions:

```
(flip elem ingredients) ==> (`elem` ingredients)
intercalate " " ==> unwords
```

Giving you:

```
canMake :: [Ingredient] -> Drink -> Bool
canMake ingredients = all (`elem` ingredients) . snd

printDrink :: Drink -> String
printDrink (drinkName, recipe) = unwords (map capitalize (words drinkName)) ++
                                ": " ++
                                intercalate ", " (map capitalize recipe)
                                where capitalize (x : xs) = toUpper x : xs
```

---

**All together we have:**

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

type Drink = (DrinkName, [Ingredient])
type DrinkName = String
type Ingredient = String

-- parsing the file of drink recipes
drinksFile :: GenParser Char st [Drink]
drinksFile =  endBy drink (char '\n')

-- parsing each drink recipe
drink :: GenParser Char st Drink
drink =  do first <- drinkName
            next  <- recipe
            return (first, next)

-- parsing the drink name
drinkName :: GenParser Char st DrinkName
drinkName =  do name <- many (noneOf ":")
                sep  <- many (char ':')
                return name

-- parsing the recipe into a list of ingredients
recipe :: GenParser Char st [Ingredient]
recipe =  sepBy (many (noneOf ",\n")) (char ',')

canMake :: [Ingredient] -> Drink -> Bool
canMake ingredients = all (`elem` ingredients) . snd

filterbyIngredients :: [Ingredient] -> [Drink] -> [Drink]
filterbyIngredients = filter <$> canMake

-- pretty prints a drink with its recipe
printDrink :: Drink -> String
printDrink (drinkName, recipe) = unwords (map capitalize (words drinkName)) ++
                                ": " ++
                                intercalate ", " (map capitalize recipe)
                                where capitalize (x : xs) = toUpper x : xs

showPossibleDrinks :: [Ingredient] -> [Drink] -> String
showPossibleDrinks ingredients = showDrinks . filterbyIngredients ingredients

showDrinks :: [Drink] -> String
showDrinks =  unlines . map printDrink

main = do drinks      <- readFile "drinks"
          ingredients <- readFile "ingredients"
          putStrLn $ 
              case parse drinksFile "drinksFile" drinks of
              Left error         -> "Error parsing drinks file."
              Right parsedDrinks -> showPossibleDrinks (lines ingredients) parsedDrinks
```